# How can I bind Ctrl and the Number Pad / (forward slash) in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to be able to do a KeyBinding on `Ctrl+/`.  But not the `/` that is on the same key as the `?` (on the main keyboard).  I want to do it on the number pad key of `/`.

To make it work with the main keyboard / this works:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding ElementName=window, DataContext.KeyBindingCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Gesture, RelativeSource Self}}"
                      Gesture="CTRL+Question"
```

It uses Question because it gets the shifted value when control is pressed (I guess).

But that does not work for the numpad `/` key.

**Anyone know what the [Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx) representation of the number pad `/` key is?**

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the key name is `Divide`.  Took just a bit more searching.

Comment: I didn't even think of that, but looking back... why **didn't** I think of this.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 - Yeah, it is one of those that is glaring obvious once you see it.  :)