# WPF Input Key Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="0" Command="{Binding ZeroCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="1" Command="{Binding OneCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="2" Command="{Binding TwoCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="3" Command="{Binding ThreeCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="4" Command="{Binding FourCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="5" Command="{Binding FiveCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="6" Command="{Binding SixCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="7" Command="{Binding SevenCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="8" Command="{Binding EightCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="9" Command="{Binding NienCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="OemPlus" Command="{Binding PlusCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="OemMinus" Command="{Binding MinusCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="OemBackslash" Command="{Binding DevideCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="Multiply" Command="{Binding MultiplyCommand}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding EqualsCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I was creating a basic calculator app when I ran into this issue. I am getting a compilation error '0' can not be used as a value for 'Key'. Numbers are not valid enumeration values. In fact OemMinus is the only command that is being bound.

I think could fix this by creating a InputBindingConfiguration class with a singleton, define the keys there and bind to those keys but I was wondering if there was a way of doing this purely in Xaml ?

Comment: You need to provide a valid value for the `Key` property. Valid values would be names of the enumeration values for the [System.Windows.Input.Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx) enum type. So where you have e.g. `"0"`, you need to instead have `"D0"`. See the documentation for the rest of the value names that are valid.

Comment: I personally find this question very relevant - while I was providing key values I was surprised that WPF autocomplete provides purely numerical options, I thought that was done through a value converter. Clearly it accepts only `D-` values for numerical keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the proper key binding below 
Link : [WPFKeyBindings](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFKeyBindings_3.aspx)

**Basic Keys**

**Key   - Code  Key(s)**

A - Z   The basic letter keys.

D0 - D9 The numeric keys from the main section of the keyboard.
Space   The space bar.

F1 - F24    The function keys.

Comment: What about the forward slash ?

Comment: key name is Divide . check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019447/how-can-i-bind-ctrl-and-the-number-pad-forward-slash-in-wpf